# Complex regular expression in angular routes

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

We are migrating our website from YII2 to AngularJS (6.1). In YII2 we are using regular expressions for some URL 
Like:-

```
 s/<content:[\w\ ,.]+>-wholesale-supplier-in-<country:\w+>
```

So we added this regular expression in app-routing.module.ts file

We tried to add same regular expression in app-routing.module.ts file, because we don't wanna change our URLS. So we added this code in angular routes file

```
const routes: Routes = 
      [{
         path:'s/:searchstring-wholesale-supplier-in-:country',
         component:SearchdataComponent
    }}
```

We also tried this

```
     const routes: Routes = 
      [{
         regex:'s/<searchstring:[\w\ ,.]+>-wholesale-supplier-in-<country:\w+>',
         path:'s/:searchstring-wholesale-supplier-in-:country',
         component:SearchdataComponent
    }}
```

But when we use this type of regular expression then its showing

```
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 's/apple-wholesale-supplier-in-canada'
```

and with second code we are not able to access any parameters.

How we can achieve same URL routing in angular?

Comment: Then how we can achieve same URL with parameters in angular?

Comment: angular doesn't support this kind of routing. you pretty much would have to change your routes to look like `s/:searchstring/wholesale-supplier/:country` the only thing that looks like maybe would work is a custom UrlMatcher

Comment: But if we change our URL's then we will lost all google ranking and SEO.

Comment: check this... seems like it might work? https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher

Comment: You could try rewrite rules at the webserver level. Or 301 redirections (I'm not sure of 301 redirections impact on so though)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write a custom matcher.  I'm using your regex here and haven't tested it but will take your word that it works, define your matcher like:

```
function customMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  let re = /<content:[\w\ ,.]+>-wholesale-supplier-in-<country:\w+>/;
  return url.length === 2 && url[0].path === 's' && re.test(url[1].path) ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
}
```

then define your route:

```
{
     matcher: customMatcher,
     component:SearchdataComponent
}
```

this is untested but should have the desired result of matching. But you'll still have to parse out your parameters on your own.

Comment: Sorry, But getting this

Invalid configuration of route 's/:searchstring': path and matcher cannot be used together

Comment: try removing the path then i guess?

Comment: All-ready tried. same error then "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 's/apple-wholesale-supplier-in-canada'"

Comment: I'd probably test the regex then, it doesn't look like it's valid.

Comment: The specific url matching implementation there may be a special case. I’d try to write a valid one